# bottle uwsgi nginx app returns 404

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, uwsgi, bottle

OK, I've gone around and around on this and don't know what else to do: maybe someone can help. 
I'm trying to run a bottle app via uwsgi and nginx. It works fine if I run it with the bottle server, like this;
python app.py
and then point a browser to hostname:8080
but when run via nginx/uwsgi, and go to:
hostname/apps/app1
I get the 404 error handler WITHIN THE APP, which reports a 404 error. So it's running the app: it just doesn't seem to match any of the

### route "decorators". Here's the app code, which resides in /mnt/wd/www/dev/apps/app1/app.py:

```
import bottle
import os

bottle.debug(True)

app = bottle.Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def default():
  return 'app1 (bottle): I am here. '

@app.route('/hello')
@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def greet(name='Stranger'):
  return 'Hello, %s, how are you?' % name

@app.route('/show')
@app.route('/show/<input>')
def show(input=''):
  return 'You entered: %s' % input

@app.error(404)
def error404(error):
   return '<strong>app1: 404 error returned:</strong> %s' %error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
```

### app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)

### Here's my uwsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /run/uwsgi/app/app1/socket
chmod-socket = 777 
chdir = /mnt/wd/www/dev/apps/app1/
file = app.py
callable = app
master = true
uid = www-data
```

### gid = www-data

### and here is the relevant part of the nginx site file:

```
    location /apps {
   #    try_files @uri @uwsgi;
    }

    location /apps/app1 {
      include uwsgi_params;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/app1-access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/app1-error.log;
      uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/app1/socket;
```

### }

So: what can you tell me? Thanks for any help you can provide. Even something to tell me what the app thinks it's getting
as the url would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured nginx to answer on /apps/app1, so for the bottle point of view your requests are /apps/app1/hello... instead of /hello

No brainer solution:

```
mount = /apps/app1=app.py
manage-script-name = true
```

and remove the 'file' directive in uwsgi.ini

If you want to understand why WSGI works in this way, you can check how SCRIPT_NAME and PATH_INFO are managed