# AngularJS post to Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, ngroute

i'm developing a webapp in AngularJS (front-end) and Flask (back-end).

All routing is managed by AngularJS, but sometimes i need to send data with $http.post to Flask.

This is just an example

AngularJS code

```
$scope.addAccount = function(newaccount) {
    var userdata = $.param({name:"John",surname:"Wick"});
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/html";
    $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/pyfiles/newUser",userdata)
        .success(function(data,status){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data) + " " + status);  })
        .error(function(){
            alert("Error!!");    }); };  }]);
```

Flask code

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/newUser", methods=["POST"])
def newUser():
    name = request.form["name"][0]
    surname = request.form["surname"]
    return jsonify{"username":name + surname]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1",port=int("8083"),debug=True)
```

the nginx conf is

```
upstream uwsgicluster { server 127.0.0.1:8080; }

location /pyfiles {
    include        uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass     uwsgiGPI;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

the code above is very simple, but i cannot receive any data. Firebug show me error just with Indent and Post tab, so without Response, and Flask debugger doesn't print anythings.

Where is the mistake?

Regards at all

Davide

Comment: show uwsgi config too

Comment: I think you have uwsgi and nginx listening on the same socket, change uwsgi socket to something else (like 9000) and have nginx proxy upstream to that socket

Comment: `[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8080
chdir = /<application_path>/pyfiles
module = app:application
master = true
process = 5
socket = gpi.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true`

but i don't execute uwsgi --ini <file> -w wsgi to start wsgi, but just ./wsgi.py because in the run i start the server.... it's correct??

Comment: You need to run uwsgi in the way that you mentioned

Comment: same problem... so, i start nginx on port 80, uwsgi on 8080 and when in app.run?? just Debug param? regards

Comment: check the nginx error logs

Comment: probably need to restart nginx as well

Comment: and I think the uwsgi conf should be `application:app` i.e. filename:callable. In your example the actual callable is defined as `app`

Comment: if i run uwsgi --ini <inifile> i see message "Import Error: no module named flask" , but i've installed flask and it's importable from python shell....

Comment: If you are using a virtualenv you need to specify the path to that env. If not, dunno what the problem is

Comment: today i've uninstalled uwsgi and flask, create a new virtualenv and inside install via pip uwsgi and flask. Now lab works if i use a wsgi.py with a function `def application(env, start_response).......` but if i use a module with Flask i receive 404. I do uwsgi in foreground and i don't see error `WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 sec...` i think it's ok, but i cannot understand what's wrong... :-(

Comment: **IT WORKS!!!!** i've find the solution here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594617/bottle-uwsgi-nginx-app-returns-404] - in my ini file missing **mount** and **manage-script-name**. thanks @reptilicus for the patience